# How can I use __toString method for choice type field

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, tostring, fieldtype

According to this tutorial https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label I am trying to using the toString method to load my dropdown options directly from the enity `FieldTypes`:

In my FieldTypesRepository.php I created the function `toString`:

```
  public function __toString() {
    return $this->FieldTypes;
  }
```

In my PagesController.php I am using the function in my formbuilder:

```
$formBuilder->add('type', EntityType::class, array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control select2'), 'label' => 'Type',
            'class' => FieldTypes::class,
            'choices' => $FieldTypes->__toString(),
          ));
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: FieldTypes

I also tried:

```
  $formBuilder->add('type', EntityType::class, array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control select2'), 'label' => 'Type',
            'class' => FieldTypes::class,
            'choice_label' => function ($fieldTypes) {
              return $fieldTypes->__toString();
              }
        ));
```

But here I get the error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "__toString" of class
>   "App\Entity\FieldTypes".

Comment: Symfony does this automatically you don't need to do anything like `'choices' => $FieldTypes->__toString()`

Comment: @Fabian If I do not do anything else then I get the error message `Attempted to call an undefined method named "__toString" of class "App\Entity\FieldTypes".`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an EntityType Symfony automatically calls the __toString() method of the displayed entity. You either need to implement a function in you FieldType entity:

```
public function __toString(): ?string
{
   return $this->name;
}
```

or you can use

```
'choice_label' => function ($fieldTypes) {
   return $fieldTypes->getName();
}
```

in your form to have another function called.

Answer (score 0):

> In my FieldTypesRepository.php I created the function toString

Put this method in your entity `App\Entity\FieldTypes` not in your repository

Comment: But in my entity I have already this function `  public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }`